# How to make this code fit into the base class

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have lots of classes that inherit from abstract base class, which has abstract method

```
public class BaseClass<T>
{
    protected abstract void GetItems();
}
```

each subclass have almost the same implementation

```
protected override void GetItems()
{
    // some preparation code here which is the same for all sublcasses

    // calls async method that handles the result in anonymous method
    // method name is different for each of the subclass that implements it
    _model.GetXXXAsync(a =>
    {
        // same code here for all sublclasses
    });
}
```

So, basically, the difference is only in the GetXXXAsync method. This is the method signature:

```
void GetXXXAsync(Action<EntityResultArgs<T>> operationCompleted);
```

WHat would be the best way to refactor this code to place it in a base class, to avoud repeating 30 lines of code in each subclass, while changing only the method name and T type?

Comment: `GetItems` suggests that the method would return the object retrieved. Perhaps you want to call it "PopulateItems" instead, or something similar?

Comment: :) never actually thought about it, it is kind of "out of context". Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an `abstract` method that will wrap the `GetXXXAsync()` method:

```
public class BaseClass<T>
{
    protected void Getitems()
    {
        // some preparation code here which is the same for all sublcasses

        GetItemsInternal(a =>
        {
            // same code here for all sublclasses
        });
    }

    // probably needs a better name
    protected abstract void GetItemsInternal(Action<EntityResultArgs<T>> operationComplete);
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<SomeType>
{
    protected override void GetItemsInternal(Action<EntityResultArgs<SomeType>> operationComplete)
    {
        _model.GetXXXAsync(operationComplete);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative using an abstract property.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    protected abstract Action<T> GetAsync { get; }

    protected void GetItems()
    {
        // some preparation code here which is the same for all sublcasses

        GetAsync(a => 
        {
            // same code here for all sublclasses
        });
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<SomeType>
{
    protected override Action<SomeType> GetAsync { get { return _model.GetXXXAsync; } }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Jeremy, as you can see above, the method is asynhronous, and therefore no return type.

Comment: This is certainly an alternative and I thought about it, but I don't see any advantage in doing it this way.